# scrapy:Why no use of parse_item function

Tags: scrapy

Here is my Spider:

```html
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic2"
    allowed_domains = ["cnblogs"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.cnblogs.com/kylinlin/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        next_site = response.xpath(".//*[@id='nav_next_page']/a/@href")
        for url in next_site.extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,url))
        
        item_selector = response.xpath(".//*[@class='postTitle']/a/@href")
        for url in item_selector.extract():
            yield Request(url=urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url),
                          callback=self.parse_item)
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        print "+=====================>>test"
```

Here is the output:
 *2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 
127.0.0.1:6023
2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.cnblogs.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.cnblogs.com/kylinlin/> (referer: None)

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.cnblogs.com': http://www.cnblogs.com/kylinlin/default.html?page=2>

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:

{'downloader/request_bytes': 445,

 'downloader/request_count': 2,

 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,

 'downloader/response_bytes': 5113,

 'downloader/response_count': 2,

 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,

 'finish_reason': 'finished',

 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 12, 6, 46, 20, 420000),

 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,

 'log_count/INFO': 7,

 'offsite/domains': 1,

 'offsite/filtered': 11,

 'request_depth_max': 1,

 'response_received_count': 2,

 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,

 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,

 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,

 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,

 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 12, 6, 46, 20, 131000)}

2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)*

**Why crawled pages are 0?
I cannot understand why there are no output like "+=====================>>test".
Could someone help me out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2016-08-12 14:46:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.cnblogs.com': http://www.cnblogs.com/kylinlin/default.html?page=2>
```

and your's is set to:

```
allowed_domains = ["cnblogs"]
```

which is not even a domain. It should be:

```
allowed_domains = ["cnblogs.com"]
```